# SwiftUI ScrollView containing Image on tvOS

Tags: swiftui, tvos

Is there any reason why this would not scroll? The contained Image is much taller than the screen in which the ImageScroll i

```
struct ImageScroll: View {
    @State var uiImage: UIImage
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                .focusable()
        }
        .focusable()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running on a simulator?

Comment: I'm getting the same result when running on device.